# digit matching bug in sed 4.2.2?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, ubuntu, sed

I'm not a newby to sed, but I also have a hard time believing there is a horrid bug in this age-old product, so I just want to check if I'm doing something stupid by getting some more eyes on it.

I am trying to pull a group of digits out of a URL string, but sed seems to be matching each character as well as the range of numbers.

```
bdetweiler@HPSin:~$ echo "www.blah.com/012345/moreblah.html" | sed -e 's/\([[:digit:]]*\)/!\1/g'
!w!w!w!.!b!l!a!h!.!c!o!m!/!012345/!m!o!r!e!b!l!a!h!.!h!t!m!l!
bdetweiler@HPSin:~$ echo "www.blah.com/012345/moreblah.html" | sed -e 's/\([0-9]*\)/!\1/g'
!w!w!w!.!b!l!a!h!.!c!o!m!/!012345/!m!o!r!e!b!l!a!h!.!h!t!m!l!
bdetweiler@HPSin:~$ echo "www.blah.com/012345/moreblah.html" | sed -e 's/.*\([0-9]*\).*/!\1/g'
!
bdetweiler@HPSin:~$ echo "www.blah.com/012345/moreblah.html" | sed -e 's/.*\([[:digit:]]*\).*/!\1/g'
!


bdetweiler@HPSin:~$ sed --version 
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

bdetweiler@HPSin:~$ uname -a
Linux HPSin 3.13.0-62-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 14:29:36 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

On the other hand, egrep pulls this out just fine:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or am I possibly looking at a terrible bug in sed?

**EDIT 2015-10-29 07:35**
This does not seem to be specific to sed. Perl is giving me the same issues:

```
echo -n "www.blah.com/012345/moreblah.html" | perl -pe "s/.*([0-9]+).*/\1/g"
5
```

Comment: Use `+` instead of `*` (or `[0-9][0-9]*` if `+` is not supported). Otherwise, it's matching the empty string at every position.

Comment: That would make sense, but it doesn't seem to be the case. sed -e 's/.*\([0-9]+\).*/!\1/g' just produces the whole string unchanged (www.blah.com/012345/moreblah.html), and sed -e 's/.*\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/!\1/g'
Gives me the last number in the number string (!5).

Comment: Change `.*` at the beginning to `[^0-9]*`. The `.*` is too greedy and is interfering with the match of the digit string. As for `+`, it's not in POSIX standard for BRE, but it is defined for ERE. Some implementation extends BRE with `\+`, or extends sed with a flag to use ERE instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least 1 digit, if not, everything is *corresponding* to the pattern  :-)

```
echo "www.blah.com/012345/moreblah.html" | sed -e 's/\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)/!\1/g'
```

Comment: As the OP is using GNU sed, you could go for `\+` instead of `\{1,\}`, or save a few more characters using `sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]+)/!\1/g'`.

Comment: you are right, I just try to use the more generic format to allow nearly any sed to work with if *cost* is low. For smaller sed version `sed -r 's/[0-9]+/!&/g`

Comment: Thanks for the hint on the -r flag, but no dice. Doing sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]+)/!\1!/g' actually surrounds the target string with my exclamation points (www.blah.com/!012345!/moreblah.html), but then when I try to replace everything with the target string, it only captures the last digit: sed -r 's/.*([[:digit:]]+).*/!\1/g'
!5

Comment: @bdetweiler this  is due to the first `.*` that try to take the biggest possible. Try maybe `.*[^[:digit:]` instead, assuming there is at least 1 character before the digit

Comment: This has the intended effect, though it's definitely not as straightforward as I expected: `echo "www.blah.com/012345/moreblah.html" | sed -r 's/[^[:digit:]]*//g'`